# Changing the column name in GridView using HTML or C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio, gridview

The point is I have used `GridView` in my project.
And I have assigned the Values to `GridView` using the `SQLConn`, `SQlDataAdapter` and `DataSet`

```
GridView1.DataSource=ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The point is that the output shows the column name of the tables which is unfriendly for end users.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use your own column of GridView and can assign the Header text of the gridview. Go to Properties of the GridView-->Columns-->Add the column and set the DataBound to the DB Column name and Header Text Property.

And Dont forget to set the AutoGeneratedColumns property to false of the gridview

Comment: Thanks .. Perfect.. Thats Whats I Wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column name by ordinal position - although this is not a robust way if the columns get reordered:

```
grd.HeaderRow.Cells(iCount).Text = "my column name"
```

There is a (liitle known? little used?)property of the header cells called AccessibleHeaderText

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Default Name" AccessibleHeaderText="MY_FIXED_KEY_VALUE">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="CustRef" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MyField") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Its designated for page automation so:

```
For iCount = 0 To grd.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
     Dim oCol As DataControlField = grd.Columns(iCount)
     If String.Compare(oCol.AccessibleHeaderText, "MY_FIXED_KEY_VALUE", True) = 0 Then
           grd.HeaderRow.Cells(iCount).Text = "my column name"
           Exit For
     End If
Next
```

Will be quite robust.

Of course you can use case or whatever for cycling though the columns

HTH