# Change Column name(s) in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I use the following code to change the Column Name but unfortunately it won't let me do that. Please help me to solve this problem:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string s = dt.DayOfWeek.ToString();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(string.Format("col{0}", i), s);
}
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    int c = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    string str = dataGridView1.Columns[c].HeaderText;
    if (str == "Wednesday")
    {
        str = "fifth day of week";
    }
}
```

Also is there any way so that I can get all day of week after each other between specific datetimes.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is there any type of error you are facing?? In your code you are not changing the column name anywhere instead you are assigning the column name to string variable `str` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the column name in GridView using HTML or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703548/changing-the-column-name-in-gridview-using-html-or-c-sharp)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set DataGridView.Column[index].HeaderText:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

string s = dt.DayOfWeek.ToString();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(string.Format("col{0}", i), s);
}

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{

   string str = dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
   if (str == "Wednesday")
   {
       dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText = "fifth day of week";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this line to Datagridview DataBindingComplete event handler

```
 this.dataGridView1.Columns["your database column name"].HeaderText = " preferred name";
```

Answer (score 2):

The  below code will get all days of week after each other between specific datetimes and print the names of the days as column headers:

```
        DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(2012, 11, 1);
        DateTime dtEnd = new DateTime(2012, 11, 7);

        for (int i = 0; i < dtEnd.Subtract(dtStart).Days; i++)
        {
            TimeSpan counter = new TimeSpan(i, 0, 0, 0);

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(string.Format("col{0}", i), (dtStart + counter).DayOfWeek.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i can't vote it up. because i have under 15 reputation. thankssss